# Format the results of JTextArea where it doesn't skip a line?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea

I wrote a program that given a list of anything adds single quotes around it, and an apstrophe at the end so like

"Dogs are cool" becomes 'Dogs', 'are', 'cool'

except the issue is the program gives one line to the single quote character

here are the results

'190619904419','
190619904469','
190619904569','
190619904669','
190619904759','
190619904859','
190619904869','
'

see how it appends the single quote to the end of the first line
when it should be the following

'190619904419',
'190619904469',
'190619904569',
'190619904669',
'190619904759',
'190619904859',
'190619904869',

The text is inputted in JTextArea, and I do the following

String line = JTextArea.getText().toString()

and I throw it in this method.

```
     private static String SQLFormatter(String list, JFrame frame){
     String ret = "";
     String currentWord = "";
     for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
         char c = list.charAt(i);

         if( i == list.length() - 1){
         currentWord += c;
         currentWord = '\'' + currentWord + '\'';
         ret += currentWord;
         currentWord = "";
     }
         else if(c != ' '){
             currentWord += c;
         }else if(c == ' '){

             currentWord = '\'' + currentWord + '\'' + ',';
             ret += currentWord;
             currentWord = "";
         }
     }


     return ret;
 }



Any advice, the bug is in there somewhere but im not sure if its the method or some jtextarea feature I am missing.

[JTEXT AREA RESULTS][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXBKs.png
```

Comment: I think you mean a comma at the end? You wrote apostrophe.

Comment: Can you please paste in the original input. It feels as if there must have been newline characters in there, which are getting treated more like parts of the word than like spaces

Comment: also sure looks like the frame parameter is unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's a little hard to tell without the input, but there seem to be other white space, like carriage returns, in the input, which throws off your parsing. Also, if the thing has multiple white spaces or ends in white space, you might get more than you want (for example trailing comma, which I see you worked to avoid). Your original routine works on "Dogs are cool", but not as well on "Dogs \rare \rcool \r". Here is a slightly modified version that I think addresses the issues (I also pulled out the unused jframe parameter).
I also tried to think of it as the comma precedes any word but the first. I introduced a boolean for that, though it would have worked to check if ret was empty.

```
public static String SQLFormatter(String list) {
String ret = "";
String currentWord = "";
boolean firstWord = true;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
    // note modified to prepend comma to words beyond first and treat any white space as separator
    // but multiple whitespace is treated as if just one space
    char c = list.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
        currentWord += c;
    } else if (!currentWord.equals("")) {
        currentWord = '\'' + currentWord + '\'';
        if (firstWord) {
            ret += currentWord;
            firstWord = false;
        } else {
            ret = ret + ',' + currentWord;
        }
        currentWord = "";
    }
}


return ret;
}
```